# How to give default or initial selection for md-checkbox where its data comes from JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-material

I have a list of `<md-checkbox>` where it is repeated using JSON array.
I want to give an initial selection for 2 checkboxes. Please help me on this.
My js code:

```
   $scope.elecselected = [];
   $scope.toggle = function (elecitem, eleclist) {
    var idx = eleclist.indexOf(elecitem);

    if (idx > -1) {
      eleclist.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
      eleclist.push(elecitem);
    }
    console.log("item:"+elecitem+ "   List:"+ eleclist);
  };

  $scope.exists = function (elecitem, eleclist) {
    return eleclist.indexOf(elecitem) > -1;
  };
  $scope.electrical = [{"ID":"161","Value":"ABC","Name":"AAAA BBB CCC","IsDefault":"FALSE"},{"ID":"162","Value":"CDE","Name":"CCC DDD EEE","IsDefault":"Y"},{"ID":"163","Value":"EFG","Name":"EEE FFF GGG","IsDefault":"FALSE"}];
```

HTML Code:

```
<div layout="row" style="margin-left: 5px;font-size: x-small;" ng-repeat="attribute in electrical">
 <md-checkbox ng-checked="exists(attribute.ID, elecselected)" ng-click="toggle(attribute.ID, elecselected)">
   <label name="{{value.ID}}">{{attribute.Name}}</label>
 </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

I had tested with normal array values as `$scope.elecitems = [1,2,3,4,5];
$scope.elecselected = [2,4];` and this worked but while giving JSON array it is not working. Please help...

Comment: you had  a `$scope.elecselected = [2, 4]` in your example but no selected items in electrical. You should construct this beforehand or just change the exist method into `attribute.IsDefault === "Y"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DincaAdrian for the idea of giving `attribute.IsDefault === "Y"` in ng-checked. Also I had added codes to maintain the selection procedure.
Now its working fine. Some logic must be added on top of this code to get the selected values.